# Check if a command is executable

Tags: linux, bash, command, executable

How can you check if a command can be executable or not in Linux.

**Example:**

```
xeyes
```

Answer (score 10):

From `man bash` in the conditional expressions paragraph:

> -x file
>
> True if file exists and is executable.

So, you can use:

```
[ -x /usr/bin/xeyes ] && echo "File is executable" || echo "File is not an executable or does not exist"
```

Comment: This fails completely when using `-x $(which bogus)` instead of `-x /usr/bin/bogus`. For it, `which bogus >/dev/null && echo "available" || echo "unavailable"` works just fine for me.

Comment: `-x $(which bogus)` does not work for me either, but adding quotes around the expression as such: `-x "$(which bogus)"` does.

Comment: Gee, both these work -- suppose our command is `needrestart`:
`if [[ -x "$(command -v needrestart)" ]] ; then echo "yes"; else echo "nope"; fi`
or:
`if [[ -x "$(which needrestart)" ]] ; then echo "yes"; else echo "nope"; fi`

It just happens that this command is not available to regular users, only to root, so...

Answer (score 3):

If you know the location of where the command binary is kept, just do an `ls -l`. If you don't know the location first find out location using `which` command

```
$ which xeyes
/usr/bin/xeyes
```

If the command has execute permission ( `x` ) set, then it is executable.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/

-rw-rw-r-- 1 arushirai arushirai 0 May 23 11:58 123
-rwxrwxr-x 1 arushirai arushirai 0 May 23 11:58 xeyes
```

The `-x <filename>` actually checks if the file has execute permission set

**Explanation:**

THe first column of ls -l shows the permission on file.

```
-rwxrwxr-x
```

- r is read permission
- w is write permission
- x is execute permission

> -rwxrwxr-x

- 1st bit: tells `type of file` ( `-` is for regular file )
- Next 3 bits:  `owner` permission ( `rwx` : read, write and execute )
- Next 3 bits: `group` permission ( `rwx` : read , write and execute )
- Next 3  bits:  `other` permission (`r-x` : read and execute permission )

For more information on file permissions read: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes

Comment: In case your command is symlinked (is a shortcut), you can find the source of the symlink: `readlink -f $(which your-command-here)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't known a path to the command you can use `which` to check where it is (of course, if you have it in $PATH). If you know a path to command file use `if -x /path/to/command` statement.